# Where is the web.xml file in Servlet3.0 enviroment?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

I'm looking for the `web.xml` file in a Servlet 3.0 enviroment. The reason is because I want to change my welcome file from "index.jsp" to "hello.jsp".

I know that in the `web.xml` file, there is a welcome-file-list, and I want to change this setting so that the index.jsp URL mapping is changed to hello.jsp.

So, my question is, where is the web.xml file, or if there is no such file in Servlet 3.0, how can I change my URL mapping?

I would be very pleased to get the answer this question, thanks.

Comment: In Servlet 3.0, this file is not mandatory, meaning it can be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

With servlet 3.0 its not always required, so if its not there you can add one in `WEB-INF/web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The web.xml file is created by yourself when the servlet created

Comment: Please let me know the detail step for how to create web.xml file in Eclipse.. T_T

Comment: Add one xml file in WEB-INF,and name it web.xml

Answer (score 0):

In `Servlet 3.0 web.xml` file  can be  Omitt  .

Immediate question is Then how to map ??

Like below using `Annotations` .

```
 @WebServlet(name = "MyServlet",
  urlPatterns = {"/myservlet"}, 
  initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="param1", value="value1")}
 )
 public MyServlet extends HttpServlet
 {
```

If you want to add `welcome file` and 400 ,500 status code exceptions ...blah blah ..

Create one with path `WEB-INF/web.xml` and give there .